# Create an array with increasing decimal values in C

Tags: c, arrays

Super noob question here, but I haven't worked much in C and I'm trying to create an array but it doesn't seem to be working. I have played around a bit in an online compilator but I just can't get it right.
What I want is an array containing 100 elements. I want the first element to be 8, the last element to be 12, and every element should increase by 0.04. So [8, 8.04, 8.08, ..... , 11.96, 12].
Can anyone help a newbie out? :)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: `t[i+1] = t[i]+0.04;`

Comment: `float a[100]; for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) a[i] = 8.0 + (i*0.04);`

Comment: if it starts with 8.00 and ends with 12.00, that's 101 elements...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: That is not a good method of constructing a sequence of values as it allows arithmetic rounding errors to accumulate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is code example based on Blaze snipped. This code first fills array and then prints it out.  Also as jwismar mentioned you need 101 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

        float a[101];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
                a[i] = 8.0 + (i*0.04);

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
                printf("%f\n",a[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NUMS 101

int main()
{
    double arr[NUMS];
    double start = 8.0, end = 12.0;
    double gap = (end - start) / (NUMS - 1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMS; ++i)
        arr[i] = start + i * gap;
}
```

Comment: The question asked for an array containing 100 elements. You haven't addressed that.

Comment: It's good that you provided a version that would work with either an increment of exactly 0.04(and 101 items), or an array of 100 items (and a slightly larger increment), and was easy to adapt. But it's best when an answer explains these things.

Answer (score -1):

BTW if you want to start from 8 and end with 12 then you need 101 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double arr[101];
    int i;
    arr[0] = 8;
    for (i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 0.04;
    for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        printf("%f\n",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: This implementation accumulates rounding errors as it goes.